# How to improve the performance of this django ORM query?

Tags: django, performance, postgresql

I'm using django and I'm running a postgresql database with 2.1 million records. I have a complex query which takes 20sec to run, and it takes that long because inside the query there's an aggregate `count()` function, which ends up counting 1.5million records. Having to wait 20 seconds is not acceptable for my application.

The django ORM "query" is as follows:

```
WebRequest.objects.values('FormUrl', 'Request__Platform','Request__Ip').annotate(total=Count('Request__Ip')).order_by('-total')[:10]
```

I tried using table indexes, but this hardly reduced the delay.

Now I'm considering saving the data in a table, and have the table regenerated every hour by pgadmin/cronjob/task scheduler, by e.g.

```
drop table if exists <table> tbl; select into <tabel> tbl from query;
```

I do feel like this is a sloppy fix and assume there must be a better way to reduce the time.

Are there any better approaches or do you guys consider this to be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Is there anything that could filter down the records before annotation? Dealing with that amount of records is always going to take some time

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an exact count you could try using the postgresql stats instead of making the count. Check in here for a more detailed exaplanation https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate

This would require using raw queries instead of the ORM, but that's the way to go for a lot of performance related issues